# IBM MFP How can I use mfpdev-cli upload (deploy) the .adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli, mfp

How can I use mfpdev-cli upload (deploy) the .adapter?

I need upload the .zip and .adapter in my MFP project

when I call  (in root folder)

```
 mfpdev app webupdate --build
```

and I will get projecet.zip in MobileFirst folder

then, I call    (not in root folder)

```
 mfpdev app webupdate --file project.zip
```

it's success update.

then It the same in adapter

I call   (in root folder)

```
 mfpdev adapter build
```

and get projectAdapte.adapter in target folder

then, how can I upload this projectAdapte.adapter (not in root folder and not use mfpdev adapter deploy )?

Comment: by the way, the adapter and app has been created , I just want to upload to update.

Comment: You are using MobileFirst v 8.0 ?

Comment: Yes, it's MF8, thanks a lot!!

Comment: And I must use cli to do this , is it possible use cli to deploy .adapter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want deploy an Adapter to the server first build the adapter with command

```
mfpdev adapter build
```

-which will generate .adapter file in target folder

To deploy there are two ways

1. From MFP server console click on Actions->Deploy Adapter-->Brows .adapter file in target folder -->Click on deploy
2. `mfpdev adapter deploy` (For this you need to add mfpdev server using `mfpdev server add` command )

If there are more than adapter to be build and deploy then add **all** in front of command for ex:

```
mfpdev adapter deploy all
mfpdev adapter build all
```

`mfpdev app webupdate` is used for direct update feature.

For more details about `mfpdev` cli commands see here: [MobileFirst CLI to Manage MobileFirst Artifacts](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-to-manage-mobilefirst-artifacts/).

And for more details about Adapters see here: [Developing Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/)

Comment: Is it possible use cli to deploy .adapter??

Comment: But before that you need add your server details to the terminal using command 'mfpdev server add' follow the links I have given

Comment: But I'm not in adapter  root folder , I must move .adapter to another folder and upload it (deploy), Is it possible do that?  Thanks a lot

Comment: No that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

An Adapter is a separate Maven project. If you are creating multiple adapter in a project then you can put all adapter in a one file.

[image]

> how can I upload this projectAdapte.adapter (not in root folder)?

You can build & deploy all adapter from project root folder using these command:

```
mfpdev adapter build all
mfpdev adapter deploy all
```